# MVC3 Routing - href has additional routing being added

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I have an html helper: actionLink which generates an 'img' within an 'a href'

so this:

```
Html.ActionImage"Create", "Premises", "~/Images/Views/Premises/LicensableActivitiesButton.png", "Licensable Activities", new { id = "licensableActivitiesImg" })</div>
```

generates this:

```
<a id="licensableActivitiesImg" href="/Users/Premises/Create"><img src="/Images/Views/Premises/LicensableActivitiesButton.png" alt="Licensable Activities">
```

The problem is is that it is appending '/Users/' to the beginning of the href and I don't know why.  This append is also happening in my begin form as well:

```
using (@Html.BeginForm("Create", "Premises", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "premisesForm" }))
```

gives:

```
<form id="premisesForm" method="post" action="/Users/Premises/Create">
```

My routes are simple:

```
       routes.MapRoute(
             "",
             "Premises/Premises/Create",
             new { controller = "Premises", action = "Create" }
             );


        routes.MapRoute("Default", // Route name                
                        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters                
                        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults            
                       );
```

Areas are not being used.

HTML Helper code:

```
    public static MvcHtmlString ActionImage(this HtmlHelper html, string action, string 
     Controller, string imagePath, string altText, object htmlAttributes, object routeValues)
    {
        var url = new UrlHelper(html.ViewContext.RequestContext);

        // build the <img> tag 
        var imgBuilder = new TagBuilder("img");
        imgBuilder.MergeAttribute("src", url.Content(imagePath));
        imgBuilder.MergeAttribute("alt", altText);
        string imgHtml = imgBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing);

        // build the <a> tag 
        var anchorBuilder = new TagBuilder("a");

        anchorBuilder.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes));
        anchorBuilder.MergeAttribute("href", url.Action(action, controller, routeValues));
        anchorBuilder.InnerHtml = imgHtml; // include the <img> tag inside 
        string anchorHtml = anchorBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(anchorHtml);
    }
```

Any ideas/suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Are you using Areas? Also showing the source code for your custom `ActionImage` helper might help in explaining why it generates such url.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov
No areas being used.
Html Helper Code added

Answer (score 0):

Ok,
After hours of frustration, I found that breakpoints were not being hit.

Turns out that an old assembly was being loaded.

Checking the build settings:  Project ->  Properties -> Build Tab

The Build output path was set to: /bin/x86/Debug

Changed this to: /bin

and the breakpoints are hit and the hrefs show the correct paths.

Phew!